# spark: complex join optimization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given two rdd:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([("cat", [1,2,3,4])])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(1, 100), (2, 201), (3, 350), (4, 400)])
```

What would be the most optimized way of getting:

```
rdd_expected = sc.parallelize([("cat", [1,2,3,4], [100, 201, 350, 400])])
```

Comment: A simple way would be flatmapping into ("cat", 1), ("cat", 2), ("cat", 3), ("cat", 4) and then use map to swap the positions into (1, "cat"), (2, "cat"), (3, "cat"), (4, "cat"), join with rdd2 and then combineByKey. Which is really slow.

Comment: can you use a dataframe?

Comment: would using dataframe provide really significant performance gain? Rdd is preferred though if that is not the case.

Comment: you can join using `array_contains` and then do a `collect_list` from the second rdd/df. Feels more straightforward to me.

Comment: Would that be faster than the approach that I mentioned? I am working with a pretty large dataset so performance is the key here. The combineByKey(to_list, append, extend) is extremely slow, not sure if groupByKey would be faster.

Comment: probably dataframe is faster. No need to go through Python functions in combinebykey/map/flatmap etc

Comment: Interesting, so for RDD, there isn't a way to make this process any bit faster?